# Finding all the dates / events for multiple webpages

Tags: python, screen-scraping, dateparser

I am super new to python / web scraping and I am trying to use beautifulsoup to find all the events (dates) that are listed in various web pages and then output these to a CSV file.

These are the web pages that I have been trying.

https://ir.monday.com/news-and-events/events

https://investor.okta.com/events

https://investors.atlassian.com/events-and-presentations/default.aspx

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Webscraping is usually a combination of finding the right ids/class names that you can use to filter out the data that you need.

In case of the investor.okta.com/events site page.

```css
nir-widget--field nir-widget--event--date
```

Is the className of the dates in the list.
You have to find these identifiers and search through the pages that you collect using beautifulsoup for example.

After collecting all the data that you require, you can store the data in a list/dict or in a [panda](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas) dataframe.

You can then use the csv package or the pandas function to export the results into a csv or other file format.

In order to learn more about the practicality, look up online tutorials on web scraping and csv exports to learn about setting up your development environment and how to use git for example.